# How can I set up code hints for a custom HTML attribute in IntelliJ?

Tags: html, html-editor

When I type this is my editor(IntelliJ):

```
<input type="">
```

My editor gives me a list of values for the "type" attribute: date, color, button, etc.

Is it possible to create a custom attribute, for which I can provide a set of values, just as the "type" attribute has?
For example:

```
<input flower="rose"> // and other predefined values like "sunflower" of "lavender"
```

To be clear: I want my editor (like VSCode or IntelliJ) to recognize the "flower" attribute and for me to select a flower from a list.

**Edit based on comments:**
I want this "flower" attribute to **not** be editor specific, just like "type" is not editor specific. I know about the "data-" attribute option, but as far as I know, you can't have a predefined list of values that the editor recognizes for a "data-.." attribute.

Comment: That's an editor-specific request and your question should be tagged as such.

Comment: If possible, I want this to not be editor specific, just like "type" is not.

Comment: Type is an HTML attribute from the HTML spec. You won't find an editor that recognizes some ethereal global addition to established spec. It would have to be a custom setting or plugin.